# jQuery: cannot conditionally add class to children elements

Tags: html, jquery, children

I am trying to conditionally add the class "closed-3" to all the children "input" elements of an ancestor. The ancestor should contain the classes ".summon-next-element.on-sub-sub-level". However, I get no effect - no class added, no error in the console, nothing. Here is the jQuery:

```js
$('.summon-next-element.on-sub-sub-level').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
    $(this).nextAll(".summoned-element").first().find("input").addClass("opened-3").removeClass("closed-3");
  } else {
    $(this).nextAll(".summoned-element").first().find("input").addClass("closed-3").removeClass("opened-3");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summon-next-element on-sub-sub-level">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_oui" class="oui">
  <label for="frais_renovation_oui">oui</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_non" class="non">
  <label for="frais_renovation_non">non</label>
</div>

<div class="summoned-element">

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_fichier">
    <label for="frais_renovation_fichier">
                Mes justificatifs 1
            </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_tickets" checked>
    <label for="frais_renovation_tickets">
                Mes justificatifs 2
            </label>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end of summoned element -->
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: None of the inputs in `.summon-next-element.on-sub-level` are checked. So it's going to remove the class, not add it.

Comment: If the input isn't checked, it should remove the class "opened-3" but it should instead add the class "closed-3". It doesn't do either....

Comment: you need to additionally wrap the code in a checked event for radio buttons

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, yes the issue seems to be with radio buttons, as it works fine on checkboxes. How do I wrap the code in a checked event? sorry...

Comment: @BenViatte, I have given you a solution. Check, please.

Comment: @BenViatte, wanted to get such a result?

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks to your help and others here, I finally established a working version. Much gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also necessary to wrap your logic in the radio button selection event, according to which the reduced assignment / deletion of classes will take place:

```
$(this).on('click', function() { ... }
```

In your code, there was also an incorrect class reference.

```js
$('div').find('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').addClass("closed-3").removeClass("opened-3");
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).addClass("opened-3").removeClass("closed-3");
      } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summon-next-element on-sub-sub-level">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_oui" class="oui">
  <label for="frais_renovation_oui">oui</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_non" class="non">
  <label for="frais_renovation_non">non</label>
</div>

<div class="summoned-element">

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_fichier">
    <label for="frais_renovation_fichier">
                Mes justificatifs 1
            </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_tickets" checked>
    <label for="frais_renovation_tickets">
                Mes justificatifs 2
            </label>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end of summoned element -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are not looping over each of the inputs, so when you check if the input is checked, it will always select the first inside `.on-sub-sub-level`.

Try with:

```
$('.summon-next-element.on-sub-sub-level ~ .summoned-element input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).addClass("opened-3").removeClass("closed-3");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("closed-3").removeClass("opened-3");
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.summon-next-element.on-sub-sub-level ~ .summoned-element input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).addClass("opened-3").removeClass("closed-3");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("closed-3").removeClass("opened-3");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summon-next-element on-sub-sub-level">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_oui" class="oui">
  <label for="frais_renovation_oui">oui</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation" id="frais_renovation_non" class="non">
  <label for="frais_renovation_non">non</label>
</div>

<div class="summoned-element">

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_fichier">
    <label for="frais_renovation_fichier">
                Mes justificatifs 1
            </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox info-circle right">
    <input type="radio" name="frais_renovation_justificatifs" id="frais_renovation_tickets" checked>
    <label for="frais_renovation_tickets">
                Mes justificatifs 2
            </label>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end of summoned element -->
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to get be a bit further, but still, no opened or closed classes are added....

Comment: `$("selector1").is("selector2")` is true if any of the elements selected by `selector1` satisfies `selector2`, not just the first.

Comment: @BenViatte I don't follow you, if you run the demo and inspect the inputs then you can see that closed or opened are added to them

Comment: You're right, it seems to work on the code snipped, yet for some reason on my website it doesn't... just to make things harder...